# Gray out fragment in background

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-background

I have one main Fragment which is in the background when the second Fragment gets called with `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add`. Right now the user can see the main Fragment behind the second Fragment like it should be. But i want it to be like in a grayed look. When the Second Fragment gets called, the main Fragment should gray out.
Im not sure what to google (have tried a lot of keywords) to describe this.

My idea was to take a screenshot of the main fragment (bitmap) and make it gray. Is this the right direction?

Comment: Do you tryed set alpha on background of Second fragment?

Comment: you can use setAlpha() method for transparency

Comment: @Prince  Why do so many people suggest setting an alpha value? Just because its transparent doesn't mean it's grayed out! Look at my answer for a real solution...

Comment: since transparency gives grayish effect only. Rest depends on @Daniel Storch which method he prefers.

Comment: @Prince it does not. It doesn't even remotely do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a `View` in between the `Fragments` so that it overlays the `Fragment` you want to gray out. Then set the background to be completely black and the alpha to 0 and visibility to `GONE`.

When you finally want to gray out the other `Fragment` set the visibility to `VISIBLE` and set the alpha to some value you like, maybe 0.5 or something like that. I mostly tend to animate the alpha value to get a nice effect.

---

So your layout should look something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

<View
    android:id="@+id/fadeBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="hardware"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The `Fragment` in the upper `FrameLayout` will be the one that is grayed out and you would do that like this:

```
final View fadeBackground = findViewById(R.id.fadeBackground);
fadeBackground.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
fadeBackground.animate().alpha(0.5f); // The higher the alpha value the more it will be grayed out
```

When you want to remove that effect again you would do it like this:

```
fadeBackground.animate().alpha(0.0f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // As soon as the animation is finished we set the visiblity again back to GONE
        fadeBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: With "Just put a View in between the Fragments" did you mean to add another fragment in between?

Comment: No, just a `View`, I will add an example to my answer.